# Colorindo um mapa com difererentes intensidade de cores em ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

Estou tentando realizar o plot de um mapa do brasil colorido com uma cor especifica, a "#2D3E50". No entanto, ao utilizar essa cor no mapa para colorir da menor área (tom claro) para a maior área (tom escuro) não está funcionando. Veja abaixo a cor escolhida que estou tentando inserir para as diferentes proporções.

[image]

```
library(geobr)
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
library(RColorBrewer)

dados <- structure(
  list(X = 1:27, 
      uf = c("Acre", "Alagoas", "Amapá", 
      "Amazônas", "Bahia", "Ceará", "Distrito Federal", "Espírito Santo", 
      "Goiás", "Maranhão", "Mato Grosso do Sul", "Mato Grosso", "Minas Gerais", 
      "Paraíba", "Paraná", "Pará", "Pernambuco", "Piauí", "Rio de Janeiro", 
      "Rio Grande do Norte", "Rio Grande do Sul", "Rondônia", "Roraima", 
      "Santa Catarina", "São Paulo", "Sergipe", "Tocantins"), 
      AreaTotal = c(0, 0.01, 0.07, 0, 0.6, 0, 0, 0.23, 0.14, 0.24, 1.14, 0.6, 1.96, 
                    0, 1.01, 0.21, 0, 0.03, 0.03, 0, 0.83, 0.03, 0.03, 0.64, 1.4, 
                    0, 0.15)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -27L))
states <- read_state(code_state = "all",year = 2019)
states$name_state <- tolower(states$name_state)
dados$uf <- tolower(dados$uf)

states <- dplyr::left_join(states, dados, by = c("name_state" = "uf")); states

no_axis <- theme(axis.title=element_blank(),
                 axis.text=element_blank(),
                 axis.ticks=element_blank())

ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data=states, aes(fill = AreaTotal), color=NA, size=.15) +
  no_axis + labs(size=8) + scale_fill_distiller(palette = "2D3E50", name="Áreas", limits = c(0,2))

Warning message:
In pal_name(palette, type) : Unknown palette 2D3E50
```

Veja que automaticamente ele está preenchendo com as cores verdes, e mais, as cores estão invertidas uma vez que as mais escuras estão apresentando as áreas mais baixas.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O função `scale_fill_distiller` não possui uma paleta de cores chamada `#2D3E50`, pois o pacote `RColorBrewer` não define essa paleta. Para verificar as paletas disponíveis, rode o comando `?RColorBrewer`.

Se o objetivo for sair de uma cor clara (como branco) e chegar na cor #2D3E50, recomendo usar `scale_fill_gradient`. Para criar uma sequência de cores para essa função, basta definir qual é a cor para valores baixos (`low`) e valores altos (`high`), que ela mesma se encarrega de criar as cores intermediárias.

```r
library(geobr)
#> Loading required namespace: sf
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

dados <- structure(
  list(X = 1:27, 
      uf = c("Acre", "Alagoas", "Amapá", 
      "Amazônas", "Bahia", "Ceará", "Distrito Federal", "Espírito Santo", 
      "Goiás", "Maranhão", "Mato Grosso do Sul", "Mato Grosso", "Minas Gerais", 
      "Paraíba", "Paraná", "Pará", "Pernambuco", "Piauí", "Rio de Janeiro", 
      "Rio Grande do Norte", "Rio Grande do Sul", "Rondônia", "Roraima", 
      "Santa Catarina", "São Paulo", "Sergipe", "Tocantins"), 
      AreaTotal = c(0, 0.01, 0.07, 0, 0.6, 0, 0, 0.23, 0.14, 0.24, 1.14, 0.6, 1.96, 
                    0, 1.01, 0.21, 0, 0.03, 0.03, 0, 0.83, 0.03, 0.03, 0.64, 1.4, 
                    0, 0.15)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -27L))

states <- read_state(code_state = "all", year = 2019)
#> Using year 2019
#> Loading data for the whole country
#>   |                                                                              |                                                                      |   0%  |                                                                              |===                                                                   |   4%  |                                                                              |=====                                                                 |   7%  |                                                                              |========                                                              |  11%  |                                                                              |==========                                                            |  15%  |                                                                              |=============                                                         |  19%  |                                                                              |================                                                      |  22%  |                                                                              |==================                                                    |  26%  |                                                                              |=====================                                                 |  30%  |                                                                              |=======================                                               |  33%  |                                                                              |==========================                                            |  37%  |                                                                              |=============================                                         |  41%  |                                                                              |===============================                                       |  44%  |                                                                              |==================================                                    |  48%  |                                                                              |====================================                                  |  52%  |                                                                              |=======================================                               |  56%  |                                                                              |=========================================                             |  59%  |                                                                              |============================================                          |  63%  |                                                                              |===============================================                       |  67%  |                                                                              |=================================================                     |  70%  |                                                                              |====================================================                  |  74%  |                                                                              |======================================================                |  78%  |                                                                              |=========================================================             |  81%  |                                                                              |============================================================          |  85%  |                                                                              |==============================================================        |  89%  |                                                                              |=================================================================     |  93%  |                                                                              |===================================================================   |  96%  |                                                                              |======================================================================| 100%
states$name_state <- tolower(states$name_state)
dados$uf <- tolower(dados$uf)

states <- left_join(states, dados, by = c("name_state" = "uf")); states
#> Simple feature collection with 27 features and 7 fields
#> geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: -73.99045 ymin: -33.75118 xmax: -28.84784 ymax: 5.271841
#> geographic CRS: SIRGAS 2000
#> First 10 features:
#>    code_state abbrev_state name_state code_region name_region  X AreaTotal
#> 1          11           RO   rondônia           1       Norte 22      0.03
#> 2          12           AC       acre           1       Norte  1      0.00
#> 3          13           AM   amazônas           1       Norte  4      0.00
#> 4          14           RR    roraima           1       Norte 23      0.03
#> 5          15           PA       pará           1       Norte 16      0.21
#> 6          16           AP      amapá           1       Norte  3      0.07
#> 7          17           TO  tocantins           1       Norte 27      0.15
#> 8          21           MA   maranhão           2    Nordeste 10      0.24
#> 9          22           PI      piauí           2    Nordeste 18      0.03
#> 10         23           CE      ceará           2    Nordeste  6      0.00
#>                              geom
#> 1  MULTIPOLYGON (((-65.3815 -1...
#> 2  MULTIPOLYGON (((-71.07772 -...
#> 3  MULTIPOLYGON (((-69.83766 -...
#> 4  MULTIPOLYGON (((-63.96008 2...
#> 5  MULTIPOLYGON (((-51.43248 -...
#> 6  MULTIPOLYGON (((-50.45011 2...
#> 7  MULTIPOLYGON (((-48.23163 -...
#> 8  MULTIPOLYGON (((-44.5383 -2...
#> 9  MULTIPOLYGON (((-42.91539 -...
#> 10 MULTIPOLYGON (((-41.18292 -...

no_axis <- theme(axis.title = element_blank(), 
                 axis.text = element_blank(), 
                 axis.ticks = element_blank())

ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = states, aes(fill = AreaTotal), color = NA, size = .15) +
  no_axis + 
  labs(size = 8) + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "#2D3E50", name = "Áreas", limits = c(0, 2))
```

[image]

Conhecendo um pouco de cores em hexadecimal, dá para alterar a cor inicial, para que comece em um tom de azul mais claro e não exatamente em branco.

```r
ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = states, aes(fill = AreaTotal), color = NA, size = .15) +
  no_axis + 
  labs(size = 8) + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "#D1DBE5", high = "#2D3E50", name = "Áreas", limits = c(0, 2))
```

[image]

Particularmente, não gostei do uso de `color = NA` dentro de `geom_sf`. Estados que possuem níveis muito parecidos para `AreaTotal` acabam ficando com as fronteiras quase indistinguíveis. Se esse for o objetivo, não vejo problema em deixar assim. Por outro lado, talvez seja mais interessante colorir as linhas de fronteiras para que os estados fiquem mais destacados uns dos outros.

```r
ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = states, aes(fill = AreaTotal)) +
  no_axis + 
  labs(size = 8) + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "#2D3E50", name = "Áreas", limits = c(0, 2))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-02-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Muito obrigado Marcus!!