# Colorir mapa com ggplot_2

Tags: r, ggplot2, mapas

Vi [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/496888/colorindo-um-mapa-com-difererentes-intensidade-de-cores-em-ggplot2/496909#496909) aqui no SO e tentei reproduzir para a minha situação, no entanto, ainda assim, não obtive o resultado desejado.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(geobr)
library(RColorBrewer)
```

**Baixo o mapa do Brasil**

```
br<-read_state(code_state = "all",
               year = 2010)
```

**Importo os dados**

Os dados que eu utilizo estão [nesse link](http://turismo.gov.br/dadosabertos/ementasparlamentares/ementas_parlamentares_dados2017_2018.xlsx). É do site de dados abertos do Ministério do Turismo

Como o propósito é fazer um join dos data.frames, aproveito o processo de importação dos dados  para aplicar a função `rename()`.

```
emendas<-rio::import('ementas_parlamentares_dados2017_2018.xlsx') %>% 
  janitor::clean_names() %>% 
  rename(abbrev_state = uf)
```

**Faço o join**

```
emendas_br<- inner_join(br, emendas, by ="abbrev_state")
```

**Ploto o mapa tentando replicar o método utilizado naquela resposta que mencionei:**

Aqui tentando aplicar 2 cores com `scale_fill_gradient()`:

```
ggplot()+
  geom_sf(data = emendas_br, aes(fill = valor_global), color = NA)+
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "#2D3E50", name = "V.Global", limits = c(0, 14500000))
```

[image: Usando 2 cores com scale_fill_gradient()]

**Tentei também usando uma paleta de cores:**

Aqui aplicando a paleta "Spectral" do `RColorBrewer()` com `scale_fill_gradientn()`

```
ggplot()+
  geom_sf(data = emendas_br, aes(fill = valor_global), color = NA)+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = brewer.pal(9,"Spectral"))
```

[image: Usando a paleta "Spectral" do RColorBrewer() com scale_fill_gradientn()]

**Minha dúvida:**

Por que as cores dos níveis mais elevados da escala não estão representadas no mapa?

Por exemplo, **Rondônia** é o único estado do dataset que possui o "valor_global" máximo ("14500000").

Esperava que ele fosse aparecer na cor equivalente ao máximo da escala

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A escala está correta, é só que boa parte dos dados não está aparecendo no mapa. Os dados estão por município; ao fazer a união cada UF fica com várias linhas, cada qual correspondente a um polígono. O que aparece no mapa final é o último deles de cada UF, sobreposto aos demais.

Para corrigir, sumarize os dados por UF antes da união:

```
emendas_br <- emendas %>%
  group_by(abbrev_state) %>%
  summarize(total = sum(valor_global)) %>%
  left_join(br, .)

ggplot(emendas_br) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = total/1e6)) +  # dividi por 1e6 para facilitar a leitura da legenda
  scale_fill_gradient("V. Global total\n(em milhões)", low = "white", high = "#2D3E50") +
  theme_void()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito obrigado pelas excelentes explicações Carlos Eduardo Lagosta